# FBA User Access Denied when Accessing Published page in "Pages" library

Tags: permissions, forms-authentication, access-denied

I have programmatically created a `PublishingPage` as well as custom web parts that I have added to this page. Currently this page is getting deployed to the default `Pages` library. I keep receiving the `Access Denied` error when trying to navigate to the page as an FBA user, however.

I have given full control to the `All Authenticated Users` group on the document itself, the page layout it is using, as well as the web part, but still the error persists. Does anyone have an idea of where I could find where the permission error is getting triggered?

Then page and its web parts should be available to all users, not just internal AD accounts.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you pulling information into the page from anywhere else?  Any elements on the page that may pull information from say another library will also need to have permissions set so that the user can access them.

You can check ULS logs for more details on the path and user that is denied as well.  Make sure it's not referring to your anonymous user - which would indicate an issue with forms auth.

Comment: That was the issue. My code was loading data from another list. Thanks!